# Subscript out of range error - vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to copy and paste multiple tables from excel to word but it's giving me Subscript out of range error when I am trying to define tbl. I found the codes online and is trying to modify the codes to suit my needs.

```
Sub ExcelTablesToWord_Modified()

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim tableName As String

    With dict
        .Add "TableA1", "TableA1"
        .Add "TableA2", "TableA2"
        .Add "TableB1", "TableB1"
        .Add "TableB2", "TableB2"
        .Add "TableC", "TableC"
        .Add "TableD", "TableD"
        .Add "TableE1", "TableE1"
        .Add "TableE2", "TableE2"
        .Add "TableF1", "TableF1"
        .Add "TableF2", "TableF2"
        'TODO: add the remaining WorksheetName/TableName combinations
    End With

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Set Variable Equal To Destination Word Document
    On Error GoTo WordDocNotFound
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
      WordApp.Visible = True
      Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("a.docx")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Loop Through Worksheets, and Copy/Paste Multiple Excel Tables
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        tableName = dict(sheet.Name)

        'Copy Table Range from Excel
        sheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Copy

        'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
        myDoc.Bookmarks(tableName).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False

        'Autofit the most-recently-pasted Table so it fits inside Word Document
        myDoc.Tables(myDoc.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    Next sheet

    'Completion Message
    MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
    GoTo EndRoutine

    'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'b' is not currently open, aborting.", 16

    'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like?  I don't see Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library in your list either.

Comment: 4th in your selection is `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library`, but you probably want `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library`

Comment: No, the 4th selection is Microsoft Office which may or may not include Word.  Given that there are explicit Excel and Access libraries, there may be an explicit Word library.

Comment: ok, i found it thank you pointing out my mistake, but now it's giving me a Subscript out of range error where I am trying to define tbl.

Comment: @YowE3K, due to the `Option Base 1` line at the top, the `LBound` will actually be 1. @sc1324, that `Set tbl...` line assumes the "TableA1" Table is on the first Worksheet in the Workbook, the "TableA2" Table is on the second Worksheet, etc. The error you are receiving indicates that the way your Workbook is structured does not conform to that assumption. If so, it may help if you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41351912/edit) your question, and specify the name of the Worksheet on which each Table is located.

Comment: @mjh - thanks - I missed the `Option Base 1`

Comment: If you cannot Get the Word Application object, create it! `If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`. Also it is better to Define the WordApp as an Object, this kills the error you have (you don't need to reference it in VBE on the machine you are running it).

Comment: @MJH, i updated my sheets so tableA1 is in sheet1 position and so on but it is still giving me the same error. TableA1 is in sheetname Table A-1 Summary, TableA2 is in sheetname Table A-2 Agency Class and so on... I was not sure if there is a simpler way to give locations of each table and then have a copy and paste formula and insert them on the word?

Comment: @PatricK, how exactly can I do that? which part of the codes should I modify so this will work? Thank you,

Comment: Please ensure your Workbook has no hidden Worksheets (which would alter the Worksheet "numbers"). If it does not, then please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41351912/edit) your question, and include a screenshot of the first Worksheet in the Workbook. Before taking the screenshot, click a cell in the Table, then click the "Design" tab on the Ribbon. Ensure that the screenshot shows both the "Table Name" (the left-most item on that Ribbon tab), and the Worksheet tab (which should be the left-most tab). Also, you should always tag such questions with your Excel version.

Comment: @MJH, hi, i am not sure if my question is clear but please advise.

Comment: You didn't actually do what I requested, but never mind that.  See my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code I had originally provided was based on your original model, in which the corresponding Worksheet, Table, and Bookmark in each set had a different name.

Now that you have ensured that the names of the objects in each set are identical (which is a better model), try the following procedure. The only difference is that the `Scripting.Dictionary` has been eliminated, and the Worksheet name is being used to provide both the name of the Table and the name of the Bookmark (since all three values match now).

As before, this one has also been tested in Excel/Word 2016, and is functioning as expected:

```
Public Sub ExcelTablesToWord_Modified2()

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Set Variable Equal To Destination Word Document
    On Error GoTo WordDocNotFound
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
      WordApp.Visible = True
      Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("a.docx")
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Loop Through Worksheets, and Copy/Paste Multiple Excel Tables
    For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Copy Table Range from Excel
        sheet.ListObjects(sheet.Name).Range.Copy

        'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
        myDoc.Bookmarks(sheet.Name).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False

        'Autofit the most-recently-pasted Table so it fits inside Word Document
        myDoc.Tables(myDoc.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    Next sheet

    'Completion Message
    MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
    GoTo EndRoutine

    'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'b' is not currently open, aborting.", 16

    'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

If you still receive the same error, then perhaps the Workbook is corrupted. In that case, try doing the following:

1. Create a new Workbook with one Worksheet
2. Rename the Worksheet so that its name matches the name of one of the Bookmarks in the Word document
3. **Manually** add a single, small, "testing-only" Table to the Worksheet (do not copy/paste one from the original Workbook)
4. Ensure that the Table's name is the same as the Worksheet's name
5. Copy/paste the above procedure into a new Module in that Workbook
6. Save the new Workbook
7. Ensure your Word document is open, and run the procedure

If that works, then you might consider recreating your entire original Workbook in the new Workbook. When doing so, if your datasets are large enough that you **must** copy/paste from the Original Workbook, use "Paste Special" with "Values Only" instead of just a normal Paste. Then, re-create any missing formatting manually. That way, it will be less likely that any corruption in the original Workbook will be transferred to the new one.

Comment: Hi, I modified the codes and change each bookmark, sheetname and tablename to be the same, TableA1, TableA2...and i also finish  .Add for each of my table but when I run it, it's giving me an error at sheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Copy this line, not sure why. I only have 10 sheets in my workbook, no hidden tabs.

Comment: What is the error? If it is "Subscript out of range" again, then it is likely you have an incorrect Table name in one or more of the `.Add` lines. In that case, as a test you might try running the procedure with all but one of the `.Add` lines commented. Otherwise, I'll need to know the exact error message.

Comment: I get the same error, Subscript out of range, and please see above, i finish off your codes you provided and they are in the same order as my worksheets. So my worksheet name, table name and my bookmark name are the same. My word doc's name is a.docx and my excel's name is b.xlsm.

Comment: I also tried to just do 1 table at a time, and even if that's the case, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Below will copy the first Table in every worksheet and paste into Word doc, regardless of the Table Name. The bookmark names in the Word doc assumed to be simply start at 1 with prefix "bookmark".

If specific Table names are really required, then create a Collection for the names, and loop through each Table in each Worksheet, if that table name is in the Collection then proceed to copy.

```
Option Base 1 'Force arrays to start at 1 instead of 0

Sub ExcelTablesToWord()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Object ' Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Object ' Word.Document
    Dim x As Long ' Integer


    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Set Variable Equal To Destination Word Document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then GoTo WordDocNotFound
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("a.docx")
    If myDoc Is Nothing Then Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("a.docx")
    If myDoc Is Nothing Then GoTo WordDocNotFound

    'Loop Through and Copy/Paste Multiple Excel Tables
    x = 1 ' For x = LBound(TableArray) To UBound(TableArray)
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Copy Table Range from Excel
        'Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x).ListObjects(TableArray(x)).Range
        Set tbl = oWS.ListObjects(1).Range
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            tbl.Copy

            'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
            myDoc.Bookmarks("bookmark" & x).Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False

            'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
            myDoc.Tables(x).AutoFitBehavior 2 ' (wdAutoFitWindow)

            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Completion Message
    MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
    GoTo EndRoutine

    'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'b' is not currently open, aborting.", 16

    'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like the codes went through and did the copy and paste but i dont see it anywhere in my word document.

Comment: Did you step through the PasteExcelTable part? My test Excel file and Word Doc works fine when there are existing bookmarks from `bookmark1` to `bookmark4`. Put a break on `x = x + 1` and see if the Word Doc still has those bookmarks.